# Need to allow single entry in extjs textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am developing a form in extjs 4.0.7

I need to change the format of money like comma and dot as thousand separator and decimal fraction.

For that I need to insert only one symbol in a textfield, In ExtJS I tried this code:

```
    {
    xtype       : 'textfield',
    type        : 'string',
    fieldLabel  : '1000s separator:',
    name        : 'amount_separator',
    id          : 'amount_separator',
    maxLength   : 1,
    size        : 1,

    anchor      : '30%'
}
```

but this not helps me to limit the insertion in a single symbol (',' OR '.')

How do i need to rearrange the properties of Code in the controller file.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-number

Answer (score 1):

Did you try enforceMaxLength ?
True to set the maxLength property on the underlying input field. Defaults to false

```
enforceMaxLength : true
```